How should I behave when giving a AWS Permission Set | Handling Policies to users
Context:
I've been given the task to manage the AWS IAM Identity Center (user, groups, accounts, permission sets, etc.) of my company. We have multiple developer companies that implement solutions to us. We have a fixed amount (~10) of AWS Accounts, that is shared between multiple devs of different companies, and at least we have a dev and prod environment for a AWS Account.(I cannot add more accounts). I've been handling this responsability by creating a group with the respective Permission Set for every dev company that more or less correspond to a group of functionalities, and then using the inline policies, I give them the policies they require when they cannot do an action in the aws console.
Problem:
While I try to mantain the account safe, in the sense of not letting the devs make changes in resources they should not, I feel im micromanaging them a lot and often times the time I take to give them the policies they need is blocking them from working.
Question: How should I handle the way I give them policies for their resources?

It is worth to give permissions action by action in a much more secure but more restricted policies?
It is a good idea to have trust in the external devs and giving them more broad and unrestricted resources?

What did you try and what were you expecting?
I've tried using inline custom policies for their Permission Sets.
I´ve tried using "native" aws policies.
I've learnt what policies I should give them prior to them being blocked by the action they want to perform.
Comment:
While this question is more opinion based, I believe the experience of senior Admins is highly needed since is a common experience for all cloud administrators. And there is no place to ask this questionsm since they get rejected due to the answers being experience based.

The standard advice here would be to give each workload or each company their own AWS account, either one per workload or one per environment per workload. This increases transit gateway costs if you use / need TGW. Why can't you create more AWS accounts? AWS accounts primary function these days is to define sets of users that can administer resource in the account. If you really can't create more accounts you could create VPCs for each workload / company and create simple policies that allow them to only access resources in one VPC, that way you can give wider permissions with less risk.

Hi @Tim, thank you for your advise! Yeah, I agree that one account per workload/env is the best practice, I would love to have that. ¿Why I cannot create aws accounts? Well... The problem is my expertise doing the networking of various VPC, VPN, TW, Peering, nginx configs. Also the company has already made a lot of development in a few accounts and it would be too much work to separate them, also if I mess up it would cost millions. (we are not an IT company and it shows xd).
I havent thought about the VPC trick! I will take it in consideration.

For now, Im thinking on allowing them to create stuff under a restriction of naming, that means only allowing them to do all kind of stuff, if the resource name has some key string, example: "MyLambdaXXXXX", and they only can do stuff if the resource has a "XXXXX" in its name.
The thing I might try to learn is reduce the work by creating policy templates and then micromanage the permission using boundaries.

I suggest you get a local AWS consulting company in to help you. AWS is a complex enterprise solution, if you're not careful you'll end up with insecure solutions or inflated bills. A good consulting company should be able to help you reduce you bills, even with basic things like turning development systems off outside business hours, reserved instances or savings plans, etc.
